# Shared cloud drive on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is there an option in Azure to create a "shared storage" so that all the VM's (from their respective clouds) in all the clouds (from their respective VNET's) could access this shared storage for a common purpose, e.g. backup?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "from their respective clouds" and "all the clouds." But... what have you looked at so far? Sounds like you might not have done any homework on Azure Storage yet, as blobs/tables, and queues are all accessible by any # of VMs. And there's also Azure File Service. You should consider re-asking a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Do take a look at [`Azure File Service`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx). You can essentially map a File Service Share as network drive in all the VMs provided the VMs and the storage account are in the same region. If the storage account and the VMs are not in the same region, you could write to the file service share using either REST API or storage client libraries.